# Problem with speedtest-cli

Tags: command-line, apt

I get this error when i try to run the command

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/speedtest", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('speedtest-cli==2.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'speedtest')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1986, in main
    shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1872, in shell
    speedtest = Speedtest(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1091, in __init__
    self.get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1173, in get_config
    ignore_servers = list(
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: It looks as though the speedtest-cli is no longer compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 where it is now python3.  I did install the one from https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli and it appears to work just fine.

Comment: yeah, like @Terrance said, you'll need to uninstall the `speedtest-cli` and follow the instructions on their site to install `speedtest` from their own repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt remove speedtest-cli 
sudo apt install python-pip
```

or `python3-pip` on 20.04 or newer

```
pip install speedtest_cli
speedtest
```

Comment: or in some (ubuntu 20.04) cases - apt install python3-pip

Comment: Yeah it's python3-pip, but it worked, lots of thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The answer points to the correct solution, however, here is what I did:

1. Remove the package

   ```
   $ sudo apt remove speedtest-cli [sudo] password for user:  
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done 
   The following packages will be REMOVED:  
     speedtest-cli
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   After this operation, 106 kB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  
   (Reading database ... 434307 files and directories currently installed.) 
   Removing speedtest-cli (2.1.2-2) ...
   Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
   ```
2. Install the speedtest_cli package using pip3

   ```
   $ pip3 install speedtest_cli
   Collecting speedtest_cli
   Downloading speedtest_cli-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
   Installing collected packages: speedtest-cli
   WARNING: The scripts speedtest and speedtest-cli are installed in
    '/home/user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning,
    use --no-warn-script-location.
   Successfully installed speedtest-cli-2.1.3
   ```
3. Run `vim ~/.profile` (or use your favourite text editor) and add this line at the end:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
   ```

   save the file
   run `source ~/.profile`

   (editor's note: this step may be unnecessary as `.profile` may contain a line that adds `.local/bin` to PATH if it exists - read the file first.)
4. Run the program

   ```
   $ speedtest
   Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
   Testing from Asahi Net (14.3.70.30)...
   Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
   Selecting best server based on ping...
   Hosted by GLBB Japan (Tokyo) [2.12 km]: 6.547 ms
   Testing download speed................................................................................
   Download: 74.92 Mbit/s
   Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
   Upload: 173.11 Mbit/s
   ```

My system: Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit - Enjoy!

Comment: Please use code formatting for code. This is very difficult to read and I can't fix it properly because the quote formatting button destroys all the original line breaks. :(

Comment: This is also identical to the original answer, except for the `$PATH` changes, which you should have stated in a comment, which you can do when you get 20 reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions, just trying to help others with less GNU/Linux and terminal understanding.  Moderators can feel free to remove the whole post if pleased.  No hurt feelings.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 7):

Use speedtest-cli --secure if you are in 2.1.3 version

`speedtest-cli --secure`

Comment: That was my problem, thanks

Comment: same here. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

1. Open the `speedtest.py` file in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` with a text editor.
2. Go to line 1174:

   ```py
   map(int, server_config['ignoreids'].split(','))
   ```

   and replace it with this one:

   ```py
   map(int, (server_config['ignoreids'].split(',') if len(server_config['ignoreids']) else []) )
   ```
3. Save the file and run the command again.

You can also comment the line placing `#` at the beginning and add the new line. If this solution doesn't work for you, you can restore the original file easily, uncommenting the old line and deleting the new one.