# How to solve errors after installing the speed test client?

Tags: command-line, apt, python, gnome-terminal

How to solve errors after installing the speed test client?

Error after the installation of speed test

I did install it using this command:

```
sudo apt install speedtest-cli && speedtest-cli
```

no error happens during the installation once it's run it give this error, I have to retry few times same.

```
# speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/speedtest-cli", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('speedtest-cli==2.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'speedtest-cli')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1986, in main
    shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1872, in shell
    speedtest = Speedtest(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1091, in __init__
    self.get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1173, in get_config
    ignore_servers = list(
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: think you better off using their own [client](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli#ubuntu) (uninstall old client first)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with speedtest-cli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332969/problem-with-speedtest-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did uninstall and install it using official website [speedtest.net/apps/cli#ubuntu](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli#ubuntu)

Command:

```
curl -s https://install.speedtest.net/app/cli/install.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install speedtest
```